# Getting values from JOptionPane and using them to create a new instance of a class

Tags: java, arrays, swing, object, joptionpane

I want to retrieve user values from a JOptionPane, I then want to use those values as parameters for the creation of a new instance of another class.
This is my code:

```
protected void addCar()
{
   String[] size = {"Large","Small"};
   String[] value = {"Valuable","Not Valuable"};

    JTextField regNum = new JTextField();
    JList carSize = new JList(size);
    JList carValue = new JList(value);

    carValue.getSelectedValue();
    System.out.println(carSize.getSelectedValue());
    Object[] fields = 
    {
        "Registration Number", regNum,
        "Car Size", carSize,
        "Car Value", carValue
    };

    JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(rootPane, fields, "Wish To Continue?", 
            JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, 
            null, null, regNum);


}//end addCar
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get the user input from the components you passed to `showOptionDialog()` after it has returned.

One thing to note: the 4th parameter of [`showOptionDialog()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog-java.awt.Component-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-int-javax.swing.Icon-java.lang.Object:A-java.lang.Object-) is the option type so it should be `YES_NO_OPTION` and not `DEFAULT_OPTION`. And the 5th parameter is the message type to which you can pass `INFORMATION_MESSAGE` for example. The other parameters are not relevant in your case.

See this example:

```
// Your code here to create components

JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, fields, "Wish To Continue?",
   JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null, null, null);

System.out.println(fields[0] + ": " + regNum.getText());
System.out.println(fields[2] + ": " + carSize.getSelectedValue());
System.out.println(fields[4] + ": " + carValue.getSelectedValue());
```

Output:

```
Registration Number: 1234
Car Size: Large
Car Value: Not Valuable
```

If you want to use these values to create an instance of another class, you can simply pass them like this:

```
OtherClass oc = new OtherClass(regNum.getText(), carSize.getSelectedValue(),
        carValue.getSelectedValue());
```

This assumed that your `OtherClass` has a constructor like this:

```
public OtherClass(String regNum, String carSize, String carValue) {
}
```

Comment: Yeah thanks this works :) Would you know how to pass these values as parameters in order to create a new instance of another class?